# Questions about Real Estate that aren't about Personal Finance or Money

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about [Real Estate](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10051/how-to-locate-a-land-survey-for-my-house) that dealt with surveys instead of personal finance. 
I agree with the commentator who says my question was border-line off-topic.

1. Did the creators of SE-Personal Finance and Money intend to exclude Real Estate questions, even though there is a Real Estate tag?
2. Would expanding the scope of SE-Personal Finance and Money to include Real Estate questions be problematic ?
3. Is there a SE site better suited for this question?

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest that question is on topic, because it involves the sale of the property.

IMHO, the **buying of**, **selling of**, **borrowing money for**, or **insuring** a piece of real estate, whether one's principal residence, a vacation home, or an investment property (owned by an individual), all fall under the category of "personal finance".

Some of the *biggest* money decisions people make in their lives involve real estate.

But there's also much about real estate that *would not* be on topic.  There's a line to be drawn, insofar as a real estate question involves a person's own financial decisions or actions.